# Loss of direction in Gauß' theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, integration

I was wondering about the following:

If I have a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I want to calculate the mean value of $E=-\nabla \phi$ over a sphere, then $E$ of course if a vector, but the mean value: $ E=-\frac{1}{V_\mathrm{sphere}}\int_V \nabla \phi=-\frac{1}{V_\mathrm{sphere}} \int_{S(\text{sphere})} \phi$ is no longer a vector. so how do I manage it to get also directional information about the mean value of $E$? What I calculated was: $\frac{1}{V_\mathrm{sphere}} \int_{S(\text{sphere})} \phi=\frac{1}{V_\mathrm{sphere}} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \phi r^2 \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$

This is the way it was done here:  [Article on electrodynamics](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0002021.pdf) on page 3

Please note that all definitions I gave to you, also apply to the notation in this article

Comment: I think you have your formulas wrong. There is no loss of information using Gauss' theorem. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).

Comment: but is it not right, that $\frac{1}{V_{sphere}} \int_{S(\text{sphere})} \phi=\frac{1}{V_{sphere}} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \phi r^2 sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$? and this will not be a vector, but rather a value

Comment: Yes, however 
$$\int_{\partial\;\text{sphere}} \phi \not= \int_{\text{sphere}} \nabla \phi$$
If you are not convinced, take for instance $\phi=1$.

Comment: ah so this is only true for actual vector fields?

Comment: Gauss' theorem, or the divergence theorem, is a special case of [Stoke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). While the latter applies for other things than vector fields, Gauss' theorem states
$$
    \int_B \operatorname{div}(E) dV = \int_{\partial B} (E\cdot n)dS
$$
where $E$ is a vector field.

Comment: could I still interpret my surface integral as something meaningful and could you please take a look at the link that I gave there in my question?

Comment: The relation used in the paper you linked is true, it is a corollary to Gauss' theorem that you can find on the wikipedia page linked earlier. Notice that the variable of integration in the RHS is a vector, and not a scalar.

Comment: I cannot find it(you mean the article on Stoke's theorem right?), could you please tell me what the surface integral had to be? if you would be so kind, you could also post it as an answer, so that you get credit for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9778/discussion-between-zuggg-and-lipschitz)

Comment: The author uses mean value formula rather than Gauss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula you want is
$$\int_V \vec{\nabla\phi}\,dV = \int_{\partial V} \phi \vec n\,dS\,,$$
where $\vec n$ is the unit outward normal to $\partial V$.